# .arff and .frt file in mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, arff

I started using the NoSQL DBMS MongoDB for a project and the first issue I faced was how to import my data into the MongoDB Database. I have a huge dataset, where files are whether .frt or .arff. Since the import command in mongodb does not support these files I'm facing a great challenge on how I can do set a mongodb database with them.

Does any one have any clue?

Comment: Just write your own program, the import program that comes bundled with MongoDB isn't anything particularly special

Comment: I'd also suggest the first issue is how you'll structure the data.

Comment: It could be exiting, writing my own import-program. I just wonder where to start. also I have no clue how the .frt files look like.

Answer (score 0):

Get an intermediary. Either code or get a tool to convert those two formats in cvs or something. I use nodejs for my server stuff which is based on javascript. That might give you a start :) Depends on what software you know to code in.